# xcode static library link error while building for iPhone device

Tags: xcode4, static-libraries, armv7

I am using xcode 4.6. The SDK is iOS 6.1. The error I got is  **"Undefined symbols for architecture armv7"** while project linking my own created static library, called "libEncrypt.a".

I am sure I have created the libEncrpt.a using architecture armv7. Using "otool -a" to verify the static library, it displays below message. Don't understand why xcode sill complains the error like **"Undefined symbols for architecture armv7"**??

```
> otool  -a libEncrypt.a 
Archive : libEncrypt.a (architecture armv7)
0100644 505/20    108 1360127518 #1/20
0100644 505/20   3604 1360127513 #1/20
Archive : libEncrypt.a (architecture armv7s)
0100644 505/20    108 1360127518 #1/20
0100644 505/20   3604 1360127513 #1/20
```

Add the detail error message blow:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_libEncrypt", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SignupViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can you show the entire error message? Are you linking to any other libraries?

Comment: Detail error message : Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_libEncrypt", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SignupViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I don't think I am linking to other lib. The lib "libEncrypt.a" is shown in "project>Building Phases>Link Binary With Libraries".

Answer (score 2):

Double check your "Build Active Architecture Only" settings in your app and static library projects.

I had this exact same issue because I had "Build Active Architecture Only" set to YES for my static library but not for my iOS app. When the iOS app tried do a Debug build it expected all architectures to exist but only armv7s was being built for the static library because I was deploying to my iPhone 5.